# How to convert from JSONB in JOOQ 3.11

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I am trying to convert from a JSONB to a Google GSON JsonElement. I am using the Converter from: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/

Codegen is compiling fine. But when I run a query I am getting an error in the DefaultRecordMapper.map function within Jooq. And when I step into this function, I can see the query has returned correctly, and my JSONB column is a PGobject.

I have double-checked the query, it works correctly within PSQL. I tried changing the type in the custom Converter from Object to PGobject but this caused the codegen to fail.

Again, I am using an exact copy of: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/

My pom.xml forcedTypes:

```
< forcedTypes >
    < forcedType >
        < userType>com.google.gson.JsonElement< /userType >
        < binding  >connection.JsonType< /binding >
        < types >.*json.*< /types >
    < /forcedType >
< /forcedTypes >
```

The query call site:

```
List<JooqPojo> data = DBConnection.sqlFetch(sql).into(JooqPojo.class)
```

The DBConnection.sqlFetch just returns a Result (as said, the error is not throwing here and I have checked the result being thrown, which is fine):

```
public static Result<Record> sqlFetch(String query) {
    Result<Record> val = createDSL(conn).fetch(query);
    return val;
}
```

The stack trace has:

```
Exception in thread "pool-18-thread-5" org.jooq.exception.MappingException: An error ocurred when mapping record to class public.tables.pojos.RawMSObj
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapper$MutablePOJOMapper.map(DefaultRecordMapper.java:828)
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapper.map(DefaultRecordMapper.java:481)
at org.jooq.impl.ResultImpl.into(ResultImpl.java:1372)
at tables.RawMSTable.getMatches(RawMSTable.java:61)
at task.MSTask$update$runnable$1.run(MSTask.kt:38)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jooq.exception.DataTypeException: Cannot convert from {"json": data} (class org.postgresql.util.PGobject) to class com.google.gson.JsonElement
at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.fail(Convert.java:1166)
at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.from(Convert.java:1055)
at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert0(Convert.java:321)
at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:313)
at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:385)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRecord.get(AbstractRecord.java:245)
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapper$MutablePOJOMapper.map(DefaultRecordMapper.java:790)
... 7 more
```

Column in TableImpl:

```
 public final TableField<RawfixturesRecord, JsonElement> FIXTURE = createField("fixture", org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDefaultDataType("\"pg_catalog\".\"jsonb\""), this, "", new JsonType());
```

Comment: Can you please post more relevant parts of the stack trace and the implementation of `DBConnection.sqlFetch(...)`

Comment: Thanks. Added both of these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the [plain SQL API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/), in case of which jOOQ simply takes your SQL input string and runs it. It cannot apply any converters or bindings when running the statement, so your JSONB mapping information does not apply. This results in `String` values (I suspect) in the result set, which cannot be auto-mapped to `JsonElement`.

You have to run your query using the jOOQ DSL instead.